# php odd file extension error

Tags: php

Not quite sure what is going on. OK so basically the script is in a "if" function and compares present image extensions to the file thats being loaded into the page as such

```
if ( $row['file_type'] == 'jpg' && 'jpeg' && 'png' && 'gif') {  

    $img = "obj.php?id=".base64_encode($row['file_path'])."&mode;thumb";

} else {

   $img = "assets/filesystem/file_extension_".$row['file_type'].".png";

}
```

If I replace "&&" with "or" it works, for JPG, PNG, JPEG and GIF but fails at else statement and does not run for all other file types so a docx would not be returned via file_extension_docx.png

Any clue as to why this is occurring? Since if I keep it at "&&" it has no problem running $img and returns thumbnails for all JPEG/JPG files but not PNG and GIF which are returned from assets as file_extension_png.png or file_extension_gif.png instead of being returned as image thumbnails via obj.php file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `$row['file_type'] == 'jpg' && 'jpeg' && 'png' && 'gif'` evaluates to something like ...

```
$row['file_type'] contains 'jpg'
AND 'jpeg' is a non empty string
AND 'png' is a non empty string
AND 'gif' is a non empty string
```

You are actually not checking the value of the variable against each of the strings.

In case you want to check if `$row['file_type']` contains one of those values ... you could just use the `in_array()` function for example:

```
if (in_array($row['file_type'], array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'))) {
  // ...
} else {
  // ...
}
```

Or you could do it explicitly

```
if ($row['file_type'] == 'jpg' || $row['file_type'] == 'jpeg' || $row['file_type'] == 'png'  || $row['file_type'] == 'gif') {
  // ...
} else {
  // ...
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: this option is more flexible imo

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( $row['file_type'] == 'jpg' && 'jpeg' && 'png' && 'gif')
```

replace by

```
if ( $row['file_type'] == 'jpg' || $row['file_type'] ==  'jpeg' || $row['file_type'] ==  'png' || $row['file_type'] ==  'gif')
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a suggestion, you can also use switch case for that, much easier.

```
switch($row['file_type']){

case 'jpg':
case 'jpeg':
case 'png':
case 'gif':
// put your if codes here

break;

// put your else code under default
default: 

break;

}
```

Comment: True can try that as well, but it will be taking more space and do the same as my code already dose in less lines

Comment: But easier to read, instead of long statement within the if block.

Comment: I agree with you on that

Comment: In the end, its your choice, but I would prefer a switch statement for its readability advantage.